# The Python code will not style

Tags: python, css, python-2.7

I can't get the css file in the folder to style. I have the file in the correct folder. Is it something to do with my indenting? I have no idea was is going on. The python code compiles and wors but the look isn't there and the page print plain.

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    #web page sections
    form_head='''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <title>Gamers R' Us Subscribing</title>
  </head>
  <body>'''

    form_body='''
  <div class="maincontainer">
    <h1>Welcome to Gamers R' Us!</h1>
    <div id="bgimg">
      <p>Gamers R' Us is a blog that talks and reviews video games daily. This form services as a way for users to receive emails based apon your preferred gaming system and preferred genre of game.</p>
      <div id="formbox">
        <h2>Subscribe Today!</h2>
        <form method="GET">
        <label>Full Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" John Doe"/><br>
        <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" me@domain.com"/><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="yes" checked>Subscribe for gaming updates and more!<br>
        <label>Select the gaming system you prefer:</label><br>
        <select name="system" class="selectbox">
          <option value="ps4">Playstation 4</option>
          <option value="xbone">Xbox One</option>
          <option value="wiiu">Wii U</option>
          <option value="pc">PC Gaming</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="radio" name="genre" value="FPS">First Person Shooter.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="genre" value="MOBA">Multiplayer Online Battle Arena.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="genre" value="RPG">Role-Playing Game.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="genre" value="RTS">Real Time Strategy.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="genre" value="Other">Other Genre.<br>
        <input type="submit" class="subbtn" value="Done" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>'''

    form_foot='''
  </body>
  </html>'''

        #if GET is requested it should display on next screen.
        #else should load page.
    if self.request.GET:
      name= self.request.GET['name']
      email= self.request.GET['email']
      system= self.request.GET['system']
      subscribe= self.request.GET['subscribe']
      genre= self.request.GET['genre']

      #displays form information submitted by user.
      self.response.write(form_head + "<div class='maincontainer'>" +
                                      '<h1>Thanks for Subbing!</h1>' +
                                      '<div id="infobox">' +
                                      '<h2></h2>' +
                                      "Name: "+name+"<br />" +
                                      "Email: "+email+"<br />" +
                                      "Preferred System: "+system+"<br /> " +
                                      "Preferred Genre: "+genre+
                                      '</div>' +
                                      '</div>' +
                                      form_foot)

    #Will display error. ** PLACE HOLDER **
    else:
            self.response.write(form_head + form_body + form_foot)

# Do not touch this.
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Comment: I suggest you use a decent python web framework and separate your templates from your python code.

Answer (score 0):

I Wager that if you use Firebug or another browser-based web app debugger, you will find that it failed to load the `css/style.css` resource. And then you will look at your code and realize that, even though you put `style.css` in a folder called `css`, you have configured only one URI for the server...for the `/` URL.

When you provide a route for `/css/style.css` and a corresponding handler, then the stylesheet will start to be loaded, and the HTML will be styled.